# running sql to insert so records and making sure am the only one on the db

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to sql. I just want so reassurance my sql is correct before I deploy it onto the live server.  Firstly it's suppose to put the database am playing with into single user mode.

It then inserts the records and puts it back to multiuser mode. However it should roll everything back if it fails.

```
ALTER DATABASE MartinLive SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
BEGIN TRY  
        INSERT INTO[dbo].[RuleSet]
           ([Id]
           ,[TypeId]
           ,[Description]
           ,[FileName]
           ,[RuleSetOrder])
     VALUES
           ('irl-appval',
           1,
           'CUstom field sale channel(XAGENTNAME)',
           'irl-appval.xbre',
           99
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Life_CompaniesRuleSet]
           ([Life_CompanyId]
           ,[RuleSetId])
     VALUES(
           6
           ,'irl-appval')
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() 
END CATCH  
 ALTER DATABASE MartinLive SET MULTI_USER
```

is this the correct way of doing what i want to archive using Microsoft SQL 
Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)

Comment: add SET XACT_abort on at the start of begin try commands,this ensures,that entire batch is rolled back when any one of insert fails

Comment: sorry forgot to mention am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1

Comment: just out of curiosity, why set single-user at all, since this will roll back any other transactions currently happening?

Comment: By "why set single-user at all, since this will roll back any other transactions currently " you're saying any current transactions that happening before I have excuted my sql? if so then that's a management thing above my pay grade

Comment: yes: "WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE" means exactly that...betting management doesn't understand that :)   Just a thought.

Comment: Yes thanks alot. My intension  wasn't being rude about it.  The way I said it may of sound rude. If so am sorry.